Proving the sum of the degrees of a graph is 2e formalization
As part of reading Introduction to Graph Theory by Richard Trudeau, I am working on a proof that the sum of the degrees of a graph is equal to 2e (e being edges). I understand the idea that since every edge connects two vertices, every new edge placed in a graph will increase the sum of the degrees by two since two vertices will have their degree increase by one. I'm not sure how to write a formal proof. I assume I can use induction since going from no connected vertices to one edge connecting vertices seems like a good base case, but I am unsure about the formal setup.
I would appreciate guidance on using induction for graph theory proofs.

That could be a good way to do it: denote $P(n)$ for "every graph with $n$ edges has sum of degrees $2n$". You can easily solve the case $n=1$ (you have one edge,...), so $P(1)$ is true. If $P(n)$ is true for some $n$, then take a $n+1$ edges graph, erase one of them, apply $P(n)$, put the edge you erased back,...

I don't think induction is the most appropriate tool for the situation. Formally, showing that adding a new edge raises the sum of degree by $2$ is arguably just as diffucult (if not more) than not using induction. It's also not as elegant and close to intuition in my opinion. If you still want an inductive proof, see below.
Non-inductive proof
A usual way to prove that two things are equal in combinatorics is to represents them as sets and find a bijection between them. In this case, since we want to prove that something is twice as much as another, it's probably better to use a two-to-one map.
Let $d(v)$ be the degree of $v$, then $d(v)$ is the cardinality of the set $E_v$ of edges containing $v$, the sum $\sum_v d(v)$ is the cardiniality of the disjoint union $\coprod_v E_v$, whose elements are of the form $(v,e)$ for $v \in V$ and $e \in E_v$. In term of equation
$$
\sum_{v \in V} d(v) = \sum_{v \in V} |E_v| = \left| \coprod_{v \in V} E_v\right| = |\{ (v,e) \mid v \in V \text{ and } e \in E_v \}|.
$$
The projection $(v,e) \mapsto e$, is the desired two-to-one map.
Inductive proof
I will do induction on the number of edge and show the inductive step, as the base case is trivial.
Suppose we have a graph with $n>0$ edges, by removing an edge, we have a subgraph with $n-1$ edges. Let $d(v)$ and $d'(v)$ be the degree of $v$ in the big and small graph respectively. The values $d(v)$ and $d'(v)$ are equal for all but precisely two values of $v$, where $d(v)=d'(v)+1$. Call the two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$. By the the induction hypothesis, we have
$$
\sum_{v \in V} d'(v) = 2n-2.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{v \in V} d(v) &= d(v_1) + d(v_2) + \sum_{v \in V\setminus \{v_1,v_2\}} d(v) \\
&= 2 + d'(v_1) + d'(v_2) + \sum_{v \in V\setminus \{v_1,v_2\}} d'(v) \\
&= 2 + \sum_{v \in V} d'(v) \\
&= 2n.
\end{align}
$$
I wrote the equations in detail as an example but no one really write proof this pedantic. People will usually omit the first two equations

The comment by Kolakoski already outlines a proof by induction for your particular problem, so I'll address your last request. My advisor usually says there are two standard ways to "grab" a graph; either by an edge or by a vertex. What this means in this particular case, is that when doing induction on graphs, it's usually good to remove either a vertex or an edge, many times it'll be good to pick a smartly chosen vertex or edge which might depend on the problem at hand (for instance, if you're dealing with trees, maybe try to remove a leaf). Here are a few problems that you can try to prove by induction.

Let $\chi(G)$ be the least number of colors needed to color the vertices of $G$ in such a way that every pair of adjacent vertices have different colors, and let $\Delta(G)$ be the maximum degree of $G$. Show that $\chi(G)\leq \Delta(G)+1$
Show that if the minimum degree of $G$ is at least $k$, then $G$ has every tree on $k+1$ vertices as subgraphs
Show that every graph has a bipartite subgraph with at least half of its edges
Show that if $G$ has $n$ vertices and has more than $n^2/4$ edges, then $G$ contains a triangle as a subgraph
Generalizing the above result, show that if $G$ has $n$ vertices and has more than $\left(1-\frac1r+\frac1n\right)\frac{n^2}2$ edges, then it has $K_{r+1}$ as a subgraph (that is, $r+1$ vertices all connected to eachother)
Show that all trees on $n$ vertices have exactly $n-1$ edges
Show that if $G$ has $n$ vertices, more than $n^2/4$ edges and $n$ is sufficiently large, then $G$ has a pentagon as a subgraph

Problem 7 is a bit harder than the rest, and problem 5 sort of violates the rule I laid at the start, but should be doable following the proof from problem 4. Those are the induction problems that are doable by a beginner and come to mind right now, but don't think they're the only ones, induction is a surprisingly useful tool in graph theory


Base case: For a fully disconnected graph with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ vertices, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} d(v_i) = 2\times e$. Proof:

A fully disconnected graph has no edges: $e = 0$. As all vertices are loose, every vertex has degree $0$: $d(v_i) = 0$ for any vertex $v_i$. Therefore, for a graph with $0$ edges, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} d(v_i) = 2\times e$.

Inductive step: If for a graph with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ vertices and $e_{previous} \in \mathbb{N}$ edges, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{previous}(v_i) = 2\times e_{previous}$, then once a new edge is added, it will be the case that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{after}(v_i) = 2\times e_{after}$, where $e_{after} = e_{previous}+1$. Proof:

Once we add a new edge, the number of edges will change from $e_{previous}$ to $e_{after} = e_{previous}+1$, and the new edge will have been added between two previously existing vertices – after all, no new vertex was added. The previous degree of one of these two vertices will have been increased by 1 to accomodate the new edge. And the previous degree of the other involved vertex will also have been increased by 1 for the same reason. Therefore,
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{after}(v_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{previous}(v_i) + 1 + 1$
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{after}(v_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{previous}(v_i) + 2$.
Let's assume the if-condition. Substitute the right-hand side according to our assumption.
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{after}(v_i) = 2\times e_{previous} + 2$      [if-condition (assumption)]
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{after}(v_i) = 2\times (e_{previous} + 1)$
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{after}(v_i) = 2\times e_{after}$.

Conclusion: For a graph with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ vertices and $e \in \mathbb{N}$ edges, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} d(v_i) = 2\times e$. Proof:

From (1) and (2), by induction. $\Box$
